# Subset and filter - lapply()

Tags: r, subset

I am running a loop using the lapply function in R, which I have successfully done! I am now trying to create a new data frame with these results using the subset function, particularly the "[,]" bracket notation.  After I do this, I am trying to filter the data frame for values < 0.2. How can I subset this?

To clarify, I want to convert the column names (2:256) of m3 and make them each a row of column 1 titles "Gene".  I then want to include the p-value, which I found using the lapply function as a 2nd column.

For instance I would like for it to look like this:

```
Gene         P-Value
P53          0.53
BRCA         0.0004
PTEN         0.1
```

...

```
lapply(m3[, 2:ncol(m)], function(i) {s <- survdiff(Surv(m3$Overall.Survival, m3$Status) ~ i) 
pchisq(s$chisq, length(unique(i)) - 1L, lower.tail = FALSE)})
```

Comment: Could you include a reproducible example? It will be much easier to help you then

Comment: Updated! @erocoar

Comment: Could you also show what your `lapply` output looks like at the moment? I take it it is a named list, where each name has its own `s`?

Comment: @erocoar it appears $P53 [1] 0.03 and so on